# Magnetic field for an infinite planar slab with variable current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

The problem:

---

An infinite planar slab of current exists about the $xy$-plane as $\mathbf{J} = J_0(1-\frac{z^2}{a^2})\hat{y}$ for $z^2 < a^2$ and $\mathbf{J} = 0$ otherwise. Find the magnetic field for $y^2 < a^2$.

---

According to the professor, $\mathbf{J}$ is in fact the current, not the current density, and the solution is $\mathbf{B} = J_0(z - \frac{z^3}{3a^2})\hat{x}$. However, I can't seem to come up with that solution.

First I tried using Ampère's Law. I chose a square loop inside the slab, which resulted in $B2l = \mu_0 \int_s{\mathbf{J}} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{s} = \mu_0J_0(z - \frac{z^3}{3a^2})$. So I end up with $B = \frac{\mu_0J_0(z - \frac{z^3}{3a^2})}{2l}$, which doesn't match up with the answer.

Next, I tried Ampère's Law again with the same loop, but this time assuming he meant $\mathbf{J}$ as the current density. That gave me $B2l = 2\mu_0J_0(z - \frac{z^3}{3a^2})l$ which simplifies to $B = \mu_0J_0(z - \frac{z^3}{3a^2})$, giving me the correct answer.

Am I doing this right? If not, where am I messing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The professor made a mistake; $\mathbf{J}$ is in fact the current density.